# Should HTTP 422 (Unprocessable Entity) be returned for invalid data?

Tags: http, http-headers

## Question

Should 422 be returned for data that is semantically correct (w.r.t. structure and types) but is considered by the server to be invalid?

## Authoritative Reference

From the [WebDAV RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#page-78):

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

## Concrete Examples

### Malformed Request

If an endpoint expects JSON, syntactically invalid JSON should be rejected as an HTTP 400 Bad Request.

```
{
    segments: [1, 2   // Missing closing bracket
}
```

### Malformed Schema

If an endpoint expects specific instructions or attributes to be present, but the request fails to meet the endpoint's schema, I *believe* this would fall under HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity as an 'instruction' that is unable to be understood.

```
{
    selectedSegments: [1, 2]   // Endpoint expects the attribute 'segments'
}
```

### Invalid data (the item in question)

If an endpoint receives data structured under the expected schema, then discovers that the contained data *within* that schema is invalid, I believe that constitutes an HTTP 200 OK response, with information pertaining to the validation errors passed along as the response body.  The question is **whether that assumption is correct.**

```
{
    segments: [1, 2]   // It is invalid to simultaneously select these particular segments, as determined by the server on request resolution
}
```

Comment: HTTP status code selection for REST responses is fuzzy to say the least. It isn't strictly defined. Most certainly though you don't return a 2xx if it's an error, so 422 looks like a best fit.

Comment: Give HTTP's responsibility as an application protocol, couldn't an 'invalid data' response be considered as a successful response to the request? It feels more in line with how most existing HTTP codes treat the actual data of a request, as opposed to the structure of the request.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/270821/do-web-applications-use-http-as-a-transport-layer-or-do-they-count-as-an-integr It doesn't really make sense to respond "Ok, but I'm not going to do that".

Comment: Makes sense.  Guess I need to adjust my mental model of how HTTP relates to the server-side application.  Want to create an answer with that response?

Comment: No, sorry, am on mobile. Feel free to self-answer.